# How to use object that I am getting as string in props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props

```
  const dark = { backgroundColor: "#2c3343", color: "#c8e5c9" };
  const light = { backgroundColor: "white", color: "black" };
  return (
    <>
      <div className="my-5 container">
        <h1>{props.heading}</h1>
        <div className="mb-3">
          <textarea
            className="form-control"
            id="myBox"
            value={text}
            rows={8}
            onChange={handleOnChange}
            style={{
              backgroundColor: props.mode.backgroundColor,
              color: props.mode.color,
            }}
          >
            asd
          </textarea>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
```

basically I am passing mode in props in this js file. Mode is a string which is either 'light' or 'dark'. On the basis of the props.mode value, I want to change color of my textbox. But css style is not happening on it. What to do? Am I doing something wrong while calling the objects. Like I want it to work in this way :-

**(consider mode is == 'dark')**

```
style = {{
  backgroundColor: dark.backgroundColor,
  color: dark.color,
}}
```

**consider mode is 'light'**

```
style = {{
   backgroundColor: light.backgroundColor,
   color: light.color,
}}
```

Also the objects light and dark that I have made gives warning that I haven't used them. I know I can use ternary operators instead of creating two separate objects and calling their values but I want to do it this way. So, I would appreciate if someone can point out the issue. Here is part of my code :-

```
const dark = {
    backgroundColor: "#2c3343",
    color: "#c8e5c9",
};

const light = {
    backgroundColor: "white",
    color: "black",
};

return (
    <>
        <div className="my-5 container">
            <h1>{props.heading}</h1>
            <div className="mb-3">
                <textarea
                    className="form-control"
                    id="myBox"
                    value={text}
                    rows={8}
                    onChange={handleOnChange}
                    style={{
                        backgroundColor: props.mode.backgroundColor,
                        color: props.mode.color,
                    }}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can dynamically access values on an object with the square brackets syntax.

```
const modes = {
  light: {...},
  dark: {...},
};

const thisMode = modes[props.mode];

// now use it like
color: thisMode.color
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use CSS dynamically so i have update your code it should work for you.

```
const customColor = {
    dark: {
      backgroundColor: "#2c3343",
      color: "#c8e5c9",
    },
    light: {
      backgroundColor: "white",
      color: "black",
    }
  }

  return (
    <>
      <div className="my-5 container">
        <h1>{props.heading}</h1>
        <div className="mb-3">
          <textarea
            className="form-control"
            id="myBox"
            value={text}
            rows={8}
            onChange={handleOnChange}
            style={customColor[props.mode]}
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    </>)
```

Answer (score 2):

Either you can do the way [@windowsill](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5708566/windowsill) mentioned or do it the following way.

```
style={
    props.mode === "light"
      ? {
          backgroundColor: light.backgroundColor,
          color: light.color,
        }
      : {
          backgroundColor: dark.backgroundColor,
          color: dark.color,
        }
  }
```

Comment: I know this works, but as I mentioned, I didn't wanted to use ternary operator syntax. I am looking for a better, more ethical way.